# Comparación de un input HTML con una expresión regular en JS

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Tengo que comprobar que un input de una contraseña en HTML lleva los siguientes caracteres comprobándolo en JS: al menos una minúscula, al menos una mayúscula, al menos un número y al menos un caracter del siguiente estilo (+-/*). Al ser una práctica para clase hay cosas extrañas como dejar campos vacíos o no usar pattern en html.

Tengo definido un formulario del siguiente modo:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="enviarFormulario()" class="formulario" id="formulario">
```

Y tengo en mi HTML el siguiente campo dentro del formulario:

```
<input type="password" class="formulario__input" name="cpasswd" id="password">
```

En el código JS tengo definida la siguiente expresión regular:

```
var passwd = new RegExp("(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\+-\/*]).{6,12}");
```

Tengo esa variable dentro de la función:

```
function enviarFormulario(){
var passwd = new RegExp("(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\+-\/*]).{6,12}");  //Ponemos \+ y \* porque son caracteres especiales de RegExp y necesitamos escaparlos.

//Comprobamos la contraseña y vemos si se ha introducido o no
var aux = document.getElementById("password");    //typeof aux = object y aux.value = (vacío), de este modo permitimos una contraseña vacía
if(document.getElementById("password").value.search(passwd) != 0 && typeof aux == "undefined" && aux.value != ''){
    alert("La contraseña no sigue el formato adecuado. Debe tener entre 6 y 12 caracteres e incluir: una letra mayúscula, una letra minúscula, un número y un caracter especial (+-/*)");
    return false;
}
```

En ella tengo definido un bucle if con la intención de que permita dejar el campo "contraseña" en blanco pero que si no está en blanco lo que aparezca cumpla la expresión regular.
Esa parte es la que falla ya que da igual qué introduzca, no entra en el bucle.

Me preguntaba cómo puedo hacer para que pueda dejar la contraseña en blanco pero si escribo algo en el campo este tenga que cumplir la expresión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso parece conveniente verificar si el string cumple la expresión regular con `.test`, este es ideal para un `if` porque retorna `true` o `false`.

Según lo que dices el input puede ser "válido" si está vacío o, en el caso de no estar vacío, si pasa la expresión regular. Una forma de verificar que no esté vacío es verificar el `length`, ya que siempre va a ser un string y 0 (cero) es equivalente a `false` y todo otro numero será equivalente a `true`.

Entonces el `if` que tienes que hacer para verificar que es incorrecto el input sería algo como "if( *el length distinto de 0* && que *no valide la expresión regular*)".

Ejemplo:

```js
function enviarFormulario() {

  var passwd = new RegExp("(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\+-\/*]).{6,12}");

  var pass = document.getElementById("password");

  if (pass.value.length && !passwd.test(pass.value)) {

    alert(`La contraseña no sigue el formato adecuado. 
            Debe tener entre 6 y 12 caracteres e incluir: 
            una letra mayúscula, una letra minúscula, 
            un número y un caracter especial (+-/*)`);

    pass.value = "";
    return;
  }

  alert("La contraseña pasa la expresión regular o está vacío el input")

}

document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", enviarFormulario);
```

```html
<input type="password" class="formulario__input" name="cpasswd" id="password">
<button id="enviar">
Enviar
</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona tal y como yo quería